# HTML5 contenteditable - child block element with contenteditable=false prevents getting focus on parent

Tags: css, html, contenteditable

I'm experiencing an unwanted behavior with contenteditable elements.
When nesting a block element with contenteditable=false in a parent with contenteditable=true, I can't get edit the parent element at all.

```css
.edit-box{
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}
.tag{
  display:block;
  background-color: red;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<div id="test" contenteditable="true" class="edit-box">
  <span class="tag" contenteditable="false">TAG</span>
</div>
```

It is only possible to edit/get focus when there's more content, besides the block element.

Browser: Chrome

Any suggestions to prevent this behavior?

Comment: Strange.. i was not able to delete the span.tag in chrome,but in FF i was able to delete it !!. maybe this question will shed some more light http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17890568/contenteditable-div-backspace-and-deleting-text-node-problems

Comment: oh, forgot to mention that chrome is the affected browser. thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

Add some content to edit within the parent element. It will be editable. I mean like below:

```
<div id="test" contenteditable="true" class="edit-box">
 <span class="someclass">Content to be editable</span>
 <br>
 <span class="tag" contenteditable="false">TAG</span>
</div>
```

Comment: sure, that would do it but if the user deletes the above content, it goes back to the original problem.