# contenteditable div with nested children won't allow edits once text is deleted

Tags: css, html

Consider a `<div contenteditable="true">` with children elements. These children are not editable.

All kinds of edits work fine within this `div`, except when the entire text is deleted. At this point, the `div` loses it's edit-ability. Things work fine in the absence of children elements.

Here's [the fiddle in action](https://jsfiddle.net/phio/zkh5ohh5/). Open on Chrome. Firefox works fine.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17890568/contenteditable-div-backspace-and-deleting-text-node-problems/18069930#18069930

Comment: I've demonstrated alternative methods worth exploring here: https://jsfiddle.net/zkh5ohh5/5/ (Consider *nesting* the `contenteditbale="true"` element *within a containing element* that will contain any other required sibling elements as well - **separate your concerns**)